# How to tell if a drop down has options to select?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to tell if a drop down has options to select?

Comment: I assume it is your fervent hope that nobody forget about the possibility that individual `<option>` elements may have the "disabled" property set to `true`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var hasOptions = !!$('#theSelect option').filter(function() { return !this.disabled; }).length;
```

maybe? This looks for `<option>` elements that are not disabled.

Comment: Yes, that's a fine thing to do.

Answer (score 15):

```
var menu = getElementById("select_id");
if(menu.options.length) {
    // has children
} else {
    // empty
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is the correct answer, assuming OP is not using jQuery.

Answer (score 10):

```
if ($("#myselect option").length > 0) {
  // Yay we have options
}
```

Comment: `length` is a property. No need for the `(` and `)`.

Comment: what happens if length is 1 ?

Comment: Kevin Bacon turns into a robot! Just kidding @Pablo. I fixed my answer. Good catch.

Comment: "There are 2 hard problems in computer science: caching, naming, and off-by-1 errors"

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#input1 option').length > 0
```

Where `#input` is the ID of the `select` element you are running this test against.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($("#myselect option:enabled").length){
   // Yay!
}else{
   // Oh, no available options
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/enabled-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Native javascript solution:

```
!!document.getElementById('jiveviewthreadsform-filter').children.length
```

(Please do not overuse jQuery, thanks)

Comment: @Pointy True but the OP never said anything about `<optgroups>`. +1 to your solution anyway, it's the best one (though a bit verbose)

Comment: Sometimes I wonder whether anybody ever uses `<optgroup>` - it's one of those tags that I sometimes completely forget about, for months at a time ...

Comment: How is this "overuseing" jquery? It's a simple operation that doesn't really put any significant overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Very hackily, you can just check its selectedIndex; since most browsers ensure that there is something selected if at all possible, it will only be -1 if there are no selectable options.