# Validating Input Fields with JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I need to check to make sure that four  fields have some kind of value in them.
I have tried these ideas:
[Check whether a select box is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039658/how-to-check-whether-a-select-box-is-empty-using-jquery-javascript)
[How to tell if a DDL has options to select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855250/how-to-tell-if-a-drop-down-has-options-to-select)

My code is currently this:

```
    function goToConfirmStep() {
    var isAllowed = false;
    var type = $(".#tShowingType option:selected").val(); //DDL
    var startDate = $("#startDate").text(); //date picker
    var startTime = $("#startTime option:selected").val(); //DDL
    var endTime = $("showingLength option:selected").val(); //DDL
    if (type.val() ) { //&&   //(type != null || type != "")
    //(startDate.text() == "" || startDate.text() == null)) {//&&
    //($('#startTime').has('option').length > 0) &&
    //($('#endTime').has('option').length > 0)) {
    alert("here");
```

I left the comments in so you can tell what I have tried.

If they have values selected (which the 'type' and 'startTime' will have one selected on load), I want to move to the next page.  I have an alert on the else to prevent them from moving forward if the fields aren't filled out.

Comment: i guess the .val() will give you the current value, in that case you can probably just check for type.val().length > 0 , which checks the length of the string

Comment: `.val()` never returns `null`, unless the selector doesn't match anything.

Comment: You don't need to use `option:selected`. The value of a dropdown is the value of the selected option.

Comment: so should I use .value() instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually had to attack it a different way.  This is what I did:

[Attacking this from a different angle.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254400/checking-input-type-text-is-empty-null-with-jquery-or-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the `&& (and)` operator because the alert gets displayed only if all the field are empty.

It should be something like:

```
function goToConfirmStep() {
    var isAllowed = false;
    var type = $(".#tShowingType option:selected").val(); //DDL
    var startDate = $("#startDate").text(); //date picker
    var startTime = $("#startTime option:selected").val(); //DDL
    var endTime = $("showingLength option:selected").val(); //DDL

    if (type == "" || startDate == "" || startTime == "" || endTime == "")
        alert("please fill in the required fields");
    else
        goToNextStep();
}
```