# Checking Input/Type Text is empty/null with jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, input

I'm stumped. I'm trying to check to see if my input type:text is empty, or null, in my JavaScript.  I currently have this:

```
        if ($("#startDate").val().trim().length() === 0)
    {
        alert("Please fill out the required fields.");
    }
```

I have tried: `.val() === ""`, `.val() == ""`, `.length() === 0`, `.length() == 0`, `.length() < 1`, `.val().length() === 0`, `val().trim().length() < 1`, `.trim().length() < 1`, `.text() === ""`, `.text() == ""`, `!$("#startDate").val()`

My HTML is:

```
<fieldset>
<label for="startDate_[pk]" style="display:block; width:100%;text-align:left">Start Time</label>
<input type="text" name="startDate_[pk]" id="startDate_[pk]" style="width:75px;display:inline" placeholder="pick date" />
@@
<select name="startTime_[pk]" id="startTime_[pk]" style="display:inline;" disabled="disabled">
@{
var time = DateTime.Now.Date.AddHours(8);
for (int i = 480; i < 1260; i += 15)
{
<option value="@i">@DateTime.Now.Date.AddMinutes(i).ToShortTimeString()</option>
}
}
</select>
</fieldset>
```

I have also tried this:

```
        $('input[class^="dateValidate"]').each(function () {
        if($(this).val().trim().length === 0)
        {
            alert("Please fill out the required fields.");
        }
```

I'm running out of ideas.

****Update****

The validation works for one selected object.  But when you select more than one, the validation only works for the first object.  Here's my code:

```
    function validate()
{
    var startDate = $('[id^="startDate"]').filter(function(){
        return $(this).val().length!==0;
    });
    var showingType = $('[id^="tShowingType"]').filter(function () {
        return $(this).val() === "";
    });
    var startTime = $('[id^="startTime"]').filter(function () {
        return $(this).val() === "";
    });
    var endTime = $('[id^="endTime"]').filter(function () {
        return $(this).val() === "";
    });

    if (startDate.length == 0 || showingType.val() === "" || startTime.val() === "" || endTime.val() === "")
    {
        alert("Please fill out the required fields.");
    }
    else
    {
        UI.goToConfirmStep();
    }
```

I have tried:

```
var startDate = $('[id^="startDate"]').filter(function(){
        return $(this).val().length!==0
var startDate = $('[id^="startDate"]').filter(function(){
        return $(this).val().length===0
startDate.length == 0
startDate.length < 0
startDate.length < 1
```

Comment: Can you post HTML as well ?

Comment: What's the problem with the one's you've tried? Are they not working?

Comment: they aren't hitting the alert.  it's just failing with no error.

Comment: try this `if($("#startDate").val().trim())` this condition should take care of falsy string (null or undefined or empty)

Comment: One thing: `$("#startDate").val().trim().length === 0`, length is not a function, but property. But I guess this is typo since you are saying there are no errors.

Comment: The selector `$("#startDate")` won't select the element in your HTML that has the `id` of: `startDate_[pk]`; you'd need `$('#startDate_[pk]')`, or simply `$('input[id^=startDate]')`.

Comment: it's working on all of my other inputs, this one just happens to be a date picker

Comment: the [pk] is loaded up onload, it's a guid that's getting passed out

Comment: @KevinFischer updated my answer, try once!

Comment: sadly, @SudhansuChoudhary, that didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have wrong id mapped- `startDate` in the selector. In your code you have IDs like `startDate_[pk]`. So you need a [starts with](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector like below.

```
 var emptyInputs= $('[id^="startDate"]').filter(function(){
     return $(this).val().length===0;
 });

if(emptyInputs.length>0){
   alert("Please fill out the required fields.");
}
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cg2jLo8q/3/)**

Comment: it hits three times because there are three tags with startDate as part of the name

Comment: and i can't really change the name at this point, without changing a ton of other code.  i think i could try a class and search for that.

Comment: okay, now it's not working with multiple input fields with different guids attached.
Example:
I select one and the validation works. but when I select more then one, the validation only works for the first one and not the rest

Comment: @KevinFischer : updated again. Didn't know this requirement :)

Comment: honestly, didn't think it would change much! testing it now.  I actually adjusted it to emptyInputs.length < 0 in my testing code.  i have updated my question up top for more information

Comment: I have updated the question with something of the things I have tried.  It's still validating the first object perfectly (YAY!), but unfortunately, it doesn't validate any of the following objects.

Answer (score 0):

You are not targetting the id correctly

```
if(!$("#startTime_[pk]").val())
```

```js
if (!$('#startTime_[pk]').val()) {
  console.log('input empty');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="startTime_[pk]" type="text" value="" />
```

**Update**

> the [pk] actually changes because it's a guid that gets loaded up on the page load

Then use the [**starts with**](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector

```
if(!$('[id^="startTime"]').val())
```

Comment: I also tried that one too.  Forgot to add that.  Will add now

Comment: @KevinFischer, then it means there is something else going on in your code. I you look at the snippet in my answer, it is working

Comment: @KevinFischer, see my updated answer, you were not targetting the id correctly for the given html

Comment: the [pk] actually changes because it's a guid that gets loaded up on the page load

Comment: it's not hitting the alert when there's nothing in the input box

Answer (score 0):

`length` is not a function. Here is an example of the above code working by removing the parenthesis after `length`

```js
 function validate() {
   if ($("#tShowingType").val() === "" || ($("#startDate").val().trim().length === 0) || ($("#startTime").val() === "") || ($("#endTime").val() === "")) { 
     alert("Please fill out the required fields."); } else { UI.goToConfirmStep();
    }
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='startDate' />
<button onclick='validate();' >Button</button>
```

Comment: it didn't hit the alert nor did it hit my else

Comment: @KevinFischer whats the rest of your jquery

Comment: `    function validate()
    {
        //if ($("#tShowingType").val() === "" || ($("#startDate").val().length === 0) || ($("#startTime").val() === "") || ($("#endTime").val() === ""))
        if (!$('[id^="startTime"]').val())// || ($("#startTime").val() === "") || ($("#endTime").val() === ""))
        {
            alert("Please fill out the required fields.");
        }
        else {
            UI.goToConfirmStep();
        }
    }
`
it's a simple function.  the ending result will combine those other input fields to create one if statement to validate

Comment: when is validate called though?

Comment: `<button onclick="validate();">Click Me</button>`

Comment: there should be a space after button and before onclick

Comment: there is.  i made a type-o on here and corrected it

Answer (score 0):

Change the condition to the following:

```
if(!$('[id^="startDate"]').val()){
        alert("Please fill out the required fields.");
    }
```